# Customize spring boot validation message from database

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

I am using spring validation to validate the Rest Controller input, I would appreciate if any one can tell me is there a possibility of throwing custom message in case of exception and the custom message should come from database rather than from a properties file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting a custom validation message source on Spring's `LocalValidatorFactoryBean`.

Your message source needs to implement the `MessageSource` interface and read its messages from the database.

Reference:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/LocalValidatorFactoryBean.html#setValidationMessageSource-org.springframework.context.MessageSource-

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html